# has_one nested routes and route error message: "No route matches [POST] "/users/3/profiles""

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-for

The error occured after submitting "Create my Profile"

Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/users/3/profiles"

Secondly, I have restarted the webbrick cli = "rails s" and I get error message saying "undefined method `user_profiles_path'" after typing "http://localhost:3000/users/1/profile/new".  Clearly I have used "resource :profile" un nested resources.  I am tearing my hair out, what happened with these errors?

```
<h1>About You</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for ([@user, @profile]) do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :name, "First name:" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
      <%= f.label :surname, "Surname:" %>
      <%= f.text_field :surname %>
      <%= f.submit "Create my profile", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>

  resources :users do
    resource :profile
  end

     user_profile POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
 new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
                  GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                  PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                  DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
            users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                  POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
         new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
        edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
             user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                  PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                  DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
         sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                    sessions#create
      new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                sessions#new
          session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                sessions#destroy
             root        /                                      static_pages#home
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand, rails has no way of knowing whether `form_for ([@user, @profile])` (assuming `@profile` is a new record) is to be routed to `/users/:user_id/profile` or `/users/:user_id/profiles`, with verb POST. In general, it will assume the plural form, so you have to explicitly tell it if you want the singular form by writing

```
form_for @profile, url: user_profile_path(@user)
```

Comment: Thank you - this has just saved my laptop from being launched out of the window. Slightly bizarre that form_for can't work out the correct target from the model associations!